# Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot, nlp-question-answering

```
Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'
```

It shows the error when I perform this

```
updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
```

I got strucked by this error anyone help me to get out of this
i can install the version of telegram --

```
!pip install python-telegram-bot==13.7
```

then it showing the error
provide an answer if you can..

Comment: How did you define `Updater`? And why do you use such an old version of the package?

Answer (score 0):

As it is written in the [documentation](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.updater.html).

> PARAMETERS:
>
> bot (telegram.Bot) – The bot used with this Updater.
>
> update_queue (asyncio.Queue) – Queue for the updates.

The `TOKEN` and `use_context` parameters should be named differently, namely `bot` and `update_queue`